# php refresh just a part of the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

helllo so i builded a countdown with php

then i noticed that i have to refresh to keep displaying it correctly.

so im using:
header( "refresh:1;url=time.php" );
inside my php ,but it refresh all the page!

is there away to put it like in a div and only refresh that part of the page..?here is how im displaying it :

```
echo "Result: {$days}d {$hours}h {$minutes}m {$seconds}s<br/>\n"; 
echo "received: 7d 0h 0m 0s<br/>\n"; 
header( "refresh:1;url=time.php" );
```

Comment: that's what happens when you use a refresh header. the WHOLE page gets uploaded. if you want to refresh just part of it, then use ajax.

Comment: Marc is right, but to make a timer like that, you should not use AJAX at all. Every second make a request to the server, that's a lot. You should only get a timestamp on load of  PHP and then make an timer with javascript that compare the timestamp. Just note that javascript use local time and PHP use server time, so there is some additional coding to do (easily found on the web).

Comment: Agreed with the comments so far: a simple JavaScript countdown will do. If you don't know how to do that, just stick your countdown page inside an `<iframe>`.

Comment: basically a user when  triger a function i store the date in data base then i check if date  exist,i start countdown for 3 days...thats why im using php,my only problem is to refresh it ,ifram it is i guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#Status').load('record.php');
    }, 1000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds
</script>
<body>
<div id="Status"></div>
</body>
```

make new php file record.php and put your countdown code in it, it will refresh div every second