# Loop by refreshing part of page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I used code from a post on this website.

> [php refresh just a part of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391037/php-refresh-just-a-part-of-the-page)

It looked like this. and its supposed to refresh a part of the website. so i used it on a test site. i tryed to refresh a timer. 
so what happend is, it refreshed, but my cpu got to 100% and the browser crashed.
its probably some kind of loop but i cant seem to find the origin

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#Status').load('record.php');
    }, 1000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds
</script>
<body>
        * CODE/HTML *
</body>
```

[EDIT] record.php:

```
<div id="Status">
    <h2><i>Refreshing</i></h2>
    <p> <?php echo date('d-m-o');?> </p>
    <p> <?php echo time();?> </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Whats in refresh.php?

Comment: this code is perfectly valid, the problem is perhaps in `record.php` if the output is too big, the browser can crash

Comment: Is not a good idea to use ajax long polling for auto refresh ( the performance is poor )
you can try instead websockets

Comment: is the posted code in record.php as well? Then you just created some kind of bomb

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Calling an asynchronous function inside an interval is a bad practice because you do not know if the function returned a result until the interval reaches the next iteration.

In your code, you are trying to load content from the server every 1 second, regardless of whether the previous call has returned a result or not.

You could call the next load inside the callback function:

```
var loadFunction = function(url) {
   $.ajax({
         url: url,
         success: function(data) {
            // After the result is available, load new content
            $('#Status').html(data);
            // Call this function after 1 second
            setTimeout(function() { 
               loadFunction(url);
            }, 1000);
         }
   });
};

loadFunction('record.php');
```

**NOTE**

Another improval would be to modify `record.php` so that it returns a **JSON** string without any HTML markup inside and build the HTML in javascript when you get the results from load method:

```
...
success: function(data) {
   $('#Status').html(buildMarkup(data));
   ...
},
...
```

and the buildMarkup function:

```
function buildMarkup(data) {
   return '<div>' + data.content + '</div>';
}
```

Comment: i tryed your code. but the cpu usage still increases to 100%

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
<div id="Status">
    <h2><i>Refreshing</i></h2>
    <p><?php echo date('d-m-o');?> </p>
    <p> <?php echo time();?> </p> 
</div>
```

is in record.php (which is being loaded), you are actually create the following structure with javascript:

```
<div id="Status">
    <div id="Status">
        <h2><i>Refreshing</i></h2>
        <p>Some date</p>
        <p>Some time</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which will be invalid HTML. I'm not sure if JQuery would get BOTH the `id="Status"` elements, but it if does you have a bomb.

Change the loaded HTML (php) to:

```
<h2><i>Refreshing</i></h2>
<p><?php echo date('d-m-o');?> </p>
<p> <?php echo time();?> </p>
```

Comment: Theres only one div with the timer inside, not two

Comment: Ah you changed the question a bit. Then nevermind, it does not apply anymore.

Comment: yeah, sorry. any other ideas on what is happening?

Comment: If the original HTML doesn't have `<div id="Status">` then what DIV does it load into the first time?